# how to combine the result as a data frame in case of vector

Tags: r

```
gender_value<-function(author){
 au<-sub("([^,]+),\\s*(.*)", "\\2 \\1", author)
 r<-GET(paste0("https://genderapi.io/api?name=",au))
 g<-content(r)$gender
 n<-c(au,g)}

author("nandan,vivek","paswan, jyoti")
```

If I want to pass more than 10000 name in a author chosen from csv file, how could I do this.

I want the write the result in .csv file after bind the result "n".
like a table form with two columns(name,gender) and more than 10000 row(eg. jyoti paswan,female)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass only first name to the API as it returns `NULL` for names with spaces or last name

```
gender_value<-function(author) {
   au <-sub("([^,]+),\\s*(.*)", "\\2 \\1", author)
   first_name <- sub("(.*)\\s+.*", "\\1", au)
   r <- GET(paste0("https://genderapi.io/api?name=",first_name))
   g <- content(r)$gender
   g <- if (is.null(g)) NA else g
   data.frame(author_name = au, gender = g)
}
```

Have a vector of names which you want to pass to the function

```
author_names <- c("nandan,vivek","paswan, jyoti")
```

and then use `lapply` to apply the function to each name. If you have names to be passed in a dataframe use `dataframe_name$column_name` instead of `author_names`.

```
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(author_names, gender_value))
df

#   author_name gender
#1 vivek nandan   male
#2 jyoti paswan female
```

You can now write `df` to csv using `write.csv`

```
write.csv(df, "/path/of/file.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: hii.. i got an irrelevant result after 100 names Sanjay Kumar Goswami male 95 
Divya Kushwaha female 96 
Ashish Kumar Singh male 97 
Rahul Datta male 98 
Radha Krishna Lal female 99 
Jitendra P. Mathuria male 100 
S. Kumar 101 S. Kumar 
Dip Kumar Singha 102 Dip Kumar Singha 
Balkrishna Tiwari 103 Balkrishna Tiwari 
D. Sarkar 104 D. Sarkar 
Shashank Gupta 105 Shashank Gupta 
Hari Shankar Singh 106 Hari Shankar Singh

Comment: @Jyoti there could be multiple reason for it. One could be certain names might return `NULL` you need to convert them to `NA` and then store. Try updated code.

Comment: Error in data.frame(author_name = au, gender = g) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Comment: after getting gender of 100 names it stop to give the gender of first author name

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue. You might want to ask a new question for this with a reproducible example.

Comment: ok, there is another problem >r<-GET("https://gender-api.com/get?name=elizabeth&key = BQuxNmsAoQpqXCrSQH") in place of elizabeth i want to pass different names with api key...how could I do this.. Plz help

Comment: n1<-c("jaya","N","A")
n1<-if(n1==c("A","B","N") NA else n1 # how I check the if condition by matching the strings
print(n1)

Comment: f(x)=x1^4+x1^3-x1+x2^4-x2^2+x2+x3^2-x3+x1x2x3   how to plot the function f(x) in R programming